# URL rewrite/redirect on azure website

Tags: .net, redirect, azure, web-config

I have a simple static html page, which I deploy to Windows Azure. I would like to add i18n. The simplest form of i18n is to create file/folder for each language. So I have following files:

- index.html
- index.pl.html
- index.jp.html

I would like to redirect user to correct language (based on `Accept-Language` header) if the page exists.

So for example:

- `Accept-Language: pl, en-gb;q=0.8` redirect to index.pl.html
- `Accept-Language: de, jp;q=0.8` redirect to index.jp.html
- `Accept-Language: de, en-gb;q=0.8, en;q=0.7` redirect to index.html

Is this possible to do only in configuration? Or should I use ASP.NET, PHP, node.js to do this in code?

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you can get the culture with:

```
<script type="text/javacript">
console.log(navigator.language);
</script>
```

So you can edit your "index.html" to something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Index</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            switch(navigator.language)
            {
                case "pl-PL": // 
                    window.location = 'index.pl.html';
                    break;
                case "ja-JP":
                    window.location = 'index.jp.html';
                    break;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        //content

    </body>
</html>
```

PS: On server side would be better, but this should work.